# Autohide Tkinter canvas scrollbar with pack geometry

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

I need help with autohiding tkinter scrollbars when it is not needed. I have found from effbot.org this code that autohides the scrollbar but only with grid geometry. I am not using grid geometry in my case. Here is my code.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont


class AutoScrollbar(Scrollbar):
    # a scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed.  only
    # works if you use the grid geometry manager.
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            # grid_remove is currently missing from Tkinter!
            self.tk.call("grid", "remove", self)
        else:
            self.grid()
        Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)
    def pack(self, **kw):
        raise TclError, "cannot use pack with this widget"
    def place(self, **kw):
        raise TclError, "cannot use place with this widget"


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        w = 1200
        h = 650
        x = self.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - w/2
        y = self.winfo_screenheight()/2 - h/2
        self.geometry("%ix%i+%i+%i" % (w, h, x, y))

        self.mainTopFrame = Frame(self, height=75)
        self.mainTopFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, bg='#ffffff')
        self.mainBottomFrame = Frame(self.canvas, bg='#000000')
        self.yscroll = Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.yscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.mainBottomFrame, anchor=NW)
        self.mainBottomFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.menuFrame = Frame(self.mainTopFrame, bg='#545454')
        self.menuFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.container = Frame(self.mainBottomFrame)
        self.container.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (MonitorPage, PlanPage, DataLogPage, HelpPage):
            self.frame = F(self.container, self)
            self.frames[F] = self.frame
            self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(MonitorPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        self.frame = self.frames[cont]
        self.frame.tkraise()

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

class AutoScrollbar(Scrollbar):
    # a scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed.  only
    # works if you use the grid geometry manager.
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            # grid_remove is currently missing from Tkinter!
            self.tk.call("grid", "remove", self)
        else:
            self.grid()
        Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)
    def pack(self, **kw):
        raise TclError, "cannot use pack with this widget"
    def place(self, **kw):
        raise TclError, "cannot use place with this widget"

class MonitorPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        self.labelFont = tkFont.Font(family="Fixedsys", size=15, weight=tkFont.BOLD)


        self.leftFrame0 = Frame(self, bg='#888888')
        self.leftFrame0.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        self.rightFrame0 = Frame(self, bg='#888888')
        self.rightFrame0.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)
        self.upLftFrame0 = Frame(self.leftFrame0)
        self.upLftFrame0.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.dnLftFrame0 = Frame(self.leftFrame0)
        self.dnLftFrame0.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.upLftLblFrame0 = tk.LabelFrame(self.upLftFrame0)
        self.upLftLblFrame0.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.dnLftLblFrame0 = tk.LabelFrame(self.dnLftFrame0)
        self.dnLftLblFrame0.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.rtLblFrame0 = tk.LabelFrame(self.rightFrame0)
        self.rtLblFrame0.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=10, pady=10)



        self.label0 = Label(self.rtLblFrame0, height=40, width=70)
        self.label0.pack()
        self.label1 = Label(self.upLftLblFrame0, height=25, width=115)
        self.label1.pack()
        self.label2 = Label(self.dnLftLblFrame0, height=10, width=115)
        self.label2.pack()


class PlanPage(tk.Frame, MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

class DataLogPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

class HelpPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rungui = MainWindow()
    rungui.mainloop()
```

Therefore, I want to autohide the scrollbar even when I am using pack geometry.I hope I made my question clear. I am very new to python and tkinter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I adapted the example from effbot.org to pack method:

```
from Tkinter import *

class AutoScrollbar(Scrollbar):
    # a scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed.  only
    # works if you use the grid geometry manager.
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            # grid_remove is currently missing from Tkinter!
            self.pack_forget()
        else:
            if self.cget("orient") == HORIZONTAL:
                self.pack(fill=X)
            else:
                self.pack(fill=Y)
        Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)
    def grid(self, **kw):
        raise TclError, "cannot use grid with this widget"
    def place(self, **kw):
        raise TclError, "cannot use place with this widget"

# create scrolled canvas

root = Tk()

hscrollbar = AutoScrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
canvas = Canvas(root,
                xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
hscrollbar.pack()

hscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

# make the canvas expandable
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# create canvas contents

frame = Frame(canvas)
frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

rows = 5
for i in range(1,rows):
    for j in range(1,10):
        button = Button(frame, padx=7, pady=7, text="[%d,%d]" % (i,j))
        button.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='news')

canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor=NW, window=frame)

frame.update_idletasks()

canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried your code. It is indeed working with pack. But why does the scrollbar appear on the center?

Comment: I'm not used to `pack` method, I usually use `grid`, but I fnally identified my mistake, the` expand=True` for the scrollbar was the culprit (I have edited the code).

Comment: I actually solved it by using 'anchor=E'. Anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I adapted this from j_4321:

```py
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk


class AutoScrollbar(tk.Scrollbar):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.geometry_manager_add = lambda: None
        self.geometry_manager_forget = lambda: None

    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            self.geometry_manager_forget()
        else:
            self.geometry_manager_add()
        super().set(lo, hi)

    def grid(self, **kwargs):
        self.geometry_manager_add = partial(super().grid, **kwargs)
        self.geometry_manager_forget = super().grid_forget

    def pack(self, **kwargs):
        self.geometry_manager_add = partial(super().pack, **kwargs)
        self.geometry_manager_forget = super().pack_forget

    def place(self, **kwargs):
        self.geometry_manager_add = partial(super().place, **kwargs)
        self.geometry_manager_forget = super().place_forget
```

Now it works with all geometry managers. It remembers the `kwargs` that were passed in and always passes them when displaying the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

TheLizzard's answer is good, but it suffers from locking up when the user resizes into the area where the scrollbar starts to oscillate between being visible and not. That can be fixed by introducing a simple time delay (I also added a bit so users can check the scrollbar's visibility as I'm not getting good results from Scrollbar.info_ismapped()):

```
class AutoScrollbar(Scrollbar):
"""A subclass of `tkinter.Scrollbar` that automatically hides and shows itself as needed. If you need to
find out if an instance of this class is currently visible, check it's :py:attr:`visible` attribute.
"""
def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
    ""
    super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
    self.geometry_manager_add = lambda: None # replaced by grid(), pack() or place()
    self.geometry_manager_forget = lambda: None
    self.visible:bool = False # needed because super().winfo_ismapped() doesn't work as expected... 
    "True iff the scrollbar is visible. Users should treat this as a read-only variable; it is only set by this class."
    self._delayTime = time.time()

@override
def set(self, lo, hi):
    if self._delay(): # do these checks only after a threshold time limit to prevent runaway oscilations in scrollbar visibility.
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            if self.visible:  # avoid calling the geometry manager too often
                self.geometry_manager_forget()
                self.visible = False
        else:
            if not self.visible: # avoid calling the geometry manager too often
                self.geometry_manager_add()
                self.visible = True
    super().set(lo, hi)
    
def _delay(self) -> bool:
    """This method prevents locking up due to bouncing between showing and hiding the scroll
    bars.  It should be called as part of the conditional to change the state of the scroll bars.
    It works by introducing a one second delay between state changes giving the user time to drag
    by the 'purgatory' in-between state, and at least preventing runaway oscilations from 
    locking up the GUI""" 
    now = time.time()
    if now - self._delayTime > 1.0:
        self._delayTime = now
        return True
    else:
        return False

@override
def grid(self, **kwargs):
    self.geometry_manager_add = partial(super().grid, **kwargs)
    self.geometry_manager_forget = super().grid_forget

@override
def pack(self, **kwargs):
    self.geometry_manager_add = partial(super().pack, **kwargs)
    self.geometry_manager_forget = super().pack_forget

@override
def place(self, **kwargs):
    self.geometry_manager_add = partial(super().place, **kwargs)
    self.geometry_manager_forget = super().place_forget
```