# tkinter responsive scrollbar according to window size

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a GUI which occupies quite a large space so some laptops with low resolution cannot contain the entire window in the screen. I wonder if it is possible to add a responsive scrollbar when the user resize the window. Just like, for example, a web browser.

It seems that the widget "Scrollbar" is not capable of doing such task.

I found an implementation on https://gist.github.com/mp035/9f2027c3ef9172264532fcd6262f3b01, which can create a scrollable frame. I wonder if it is possible to apply it to the entire window

In the above implementation, even when the window is big enough, the scrollbar still exists

[image: E]

Comment: Please provide some more detail. What research have you done? Are you using a `listbox`? If not, what widget is it that must be interactive with a scrollbar? Also, what do you mean by __It seems that the widget "Scrollbar" is not capable of doing such task.__? Please edit your question to include these details. Only then can anyone help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TheMaker I am referring to the entire window but not a specific widget. I found an implementation which is similar to my thought on https://gist.github.com/mp035/9f2027c3ef9172264532fcd6262f3b01. Thanks!

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: Whether it is possible to make the scrollbar responsive which means it appears when the user resize the window to a smaller one. But when the window is big enough to contain all widgets, the scrollbar will disappear

Comment: In the above implementation, when the window is big enough, the scrollbar still exists

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean

Comment: @TheMaker, I added a photo to make it clearer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you are looking for [Autohide Tkinter canvas scrollbar with pack geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095385/autohide-tkinter-canvas-scrollbar-with-pack-geometry).

Comment: @HenryYik, thanks! I think it answers my question!